# Verification involving arrays

Tags: dafny

First off, I want to thank Rustan and the whole community for the work you put on Dafny. It is an amazing language!

I am working on my Master's thesis which is about formal verification of virtual machines using Dafny.

This is how I define (a stripped version of) a virtual machine:

```
class VM
{
    var v: array<bv8>;
    var I: bv16;
    var memory: array<bv8>;
    predicate Valid()
      reads this
    {
        v.Length == 16
        && memory.Length == 0x0FFF
    }

    constructor Init()
      ensures Valid()
    {
        v := new bv8[16];
        I := 0;
        memory := new bv8[0x0FFF];
    }
}
```

So far so good. I have a few methods that mutate the state of this machine. In particular, here's one:

```
method parse_opcode_registers(vm: VM, opcode: bv16)
  requires vm.Valid()
  modifies vm`I, vm.v
{
    var i: int := 0;
    var bound := ((opcode & 0x0F00) >> 8) as int;

    if opcode & 0xF0FF == 0xF065
    {
        while i < bound && vm.I as int < vm.memory.Length
          decreases bound - i
        {
            vm.v[i] := vm.memory[vm.I];
            i := i + 1;
            vm.I := vm.I + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This passes Dafny's verification. However, the issue occurs when there exists a caller for this method. Namely, the following code will produce an error `call may violate context's modifies clause`:

```
method Main() {
    var vm := new VM.Init();
    parse_opcode_registers(vm, 0xF018);
}
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ensures fresh(v)` to the `Init` constructor of `VM`.

Basically, the problem is that Dafny is worried because `parse_opcode_register` claims to modify `vm.v`, but Dafny isn't sure where `vm.v` came from. Remember that Dafny analyzes the program one method at a time, so it does not look inside the constructor `Init` while analyzing `Main`. Instead, Dafny only looks at the pre/postcondition. That's why adding `fresh(v)` to the postcondition fixes it.

The meaning of `fresh(blah)` is that `blah` was freshly allocated during the execution of the method.

For more, see the [FAQ question about modifies clauses](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#i-get-a-call-may-violate-contexts-modifies-clause-error-even-though-i-know-i-am-not-modifying-anything).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was exactly the issue. I did a lot of Googling but this Wiki did not appear for some reason :)